# Convert input text to 2d array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, tile

Im trying to make a level editor for the game.
Now I can create a new map (using mouse) and click "generate" button to trace map array 
(string). After that I can simple copy the code from the output 
and use it to create a new level.

Lets say I have a class called NewLevel.as

I create a new array and paste code from output window, so I have 2d array.
Then adding tiles to stage using for loops.

```
var array:Array = 
// code below is what I get in output window
[ 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7],
[7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7]
];

for (var row:int = 0; row < array.length; row++)
{
for (var column:int = 0; column < array[row].length; column++)
{
    var tile = new Tile();
    addChild(tile);
    tile.x = column * tile.width;
    tile.y = row * tile.height;
    tile.gotoAndStop(array[row][column] +1);
} 
}
```

It works without problems,this gives me the map I created using level editor.
but what I want is that players input their "map code" and load the map they created.
I guess you have seen that in many games.

I have a textarea so users can input their string, 
how can I convert their input to 2d array and load it (as you see in example)? 
It should be 2d array.

I also added event listener to textarea

```
textarea.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changes);

function changes(e:Event):void
{
    // convert input text to 2d array to build a new map

// Do not know how to get input to use with JSON
var myStr = levelTextarea.text;

var a2:Array = JSON.parse(myStr) as Array;
trace( a2 );
}
```

Comment: I also can accept 1d array if you show how to load that level.

Comment: Just have the arrays input as single lines per sub-array.  Then split the input on "\r\n" and split each line by ",".

Comment: I do not understand split function, can you write a code for it?   And another problem is I do not know how to make input array as single line, I can update the code you see how I got my 2d array for input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSON for this kind of job, this class is available in Flash Player 11.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author 
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point

            var a:Array = [ 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7],
[7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7]
];

            var txt:String = JSON.stringify( a )
            trace( txt );

            var a2:Array = JSON.parse( txt ) as Array;
            trace( a2 );


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I never used JSON before but I tried what you say. Actually I do not have a:Array, I only have a String that looks like 2d array. So I tried to make array = JSON.parse(myString) as Array; and I got this error: Call to a possibly undefined method parse trough a reference with a static type class.

Comment: You probably compile in SWF version prior to 11. What are you using for compilation?

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot I was playing with different settings. I did what you say and I have error "Invalid JSON parse input".

Comment: I will update my first post to show what I try to do.

Comment: What is exactly the text you enter in the Textfield?

Comment: It is [ [0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]], "array" that you describes level map, you can see it in my first post.

Comment: I know, but do you put ";" at the end of TextArea, do you put extra character before or after []?

Comment: Im very hard guy to work with :) I did what you say and I get array you are talking about, but my friend this is 1d array and not 2d array, so I do not know how to build map and, place tiles on different positions, on right frames...Thats what I said when I commented my first post.

Comment: With *"[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[7,7,7,6,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7],[7,7,7,6,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7]]"* the JSON return a 2D array.

Comment: No joke, I copy and paste that in my textarea, make an array from it and after trace I see this  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,6,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,6,6,6,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7

Comment: This is normal, the trace return a String and not a variable dump. Try trace( a2.length ) and trace( a2[0] is Array );

Comment: Aahaha, finally I can accept your answer, you deserve it.

Comment: Good luck with your project.